# Harish-Chandra modules of $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: representation-theory

Let $G=PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$ and $K$ a maximal torus.
Is the category of Harish-Chandra modules of $(G,K)$ equivalent to the Category of Harish-Chandra Modules of $SL_2(\mathbb{R})$ with even $K$-types?

If yes, could you give me a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, only the even types have trivial central character.